# Adding attachments in Acess VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I need to add boxes to my form to allow me to add attachments, so I tried bounding them to the proper field in the table. (The purpose of my form is to add to an existing table) However when I try to attach items they don't match up with the right records (all of my other controls are unbound). Is there a way to make the bound move? I've tried movelast to see if I move to the last record it will update properly but so far no success.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How are you selecting the current record?  Instead of binding the text fields, use a command button event to update the current record's fields.